# Filling overlapping child divs to parent div content area

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div element that has padding and is defined with a border-box styling. I am trying to nest multiple, overlapping child divs inside the parent element and have the child divs fill the parent container, but only the content part of the parent container's box model.

The problem I am having is that the top and left absolute positioning of the child divs is being calculated by the browser correctly, but the height and width are remains the same as the total height and width of the parent div, not just the height and width of the content portion.

This is the CSS that I have tried but it is not working:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 25px 12px 12px;
    border: thin solid red;
    position: absolute;
}
.layer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Please see my jsfiddle for an example of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/dwp1v0uu/

If you inspect the "container" element, you will see it is 300px by 60px in total, but the content portion is only 274px by 21px. Each of the nested child divs are 298px by 58px, but I want them to be closer to the 274px by 21px size.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why they have to be overlapping?  Absolute positioning has some very negative consequences if you're trying to do this in a manner that will be very abstracted.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not specify the positioning of the child with the same as the padding?

(P.s. you don't need the float if you position absolute)

```
.layer {
    top: 25px;
    right: 12px;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another element between them. It'll solve your problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="layer-wrapper">
    <div class="layer">a</div>
    <div class="layer">b</div>
    <div class="layer">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwp1v0uu/2/)

Hope it helps!